# In wicket, how can I create RadioGroups that are not defined by component hierarchy/layout?

Tags: java, layout, radio-button, wicket

I am using Wicket and would like to create a grid of radio buttons using HTML, as shown below (outer lists will be displayed vertically, inner lists will be displayed horizontally).

The number of groups is variable - could be ABC, ABCD, ABCDE etc.

I would like the radio buttons grouped vertically.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
       <li><input type="radio" name="A"></li>
       <li><input type="radio" name="B"></li>
       <li><input type="radio" name="C"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
       <li><input type="radio" name="A"></li>
       <li><input type="radio" name="B"></li>
       <li><input type="radio" name="C"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
       <li><input type="radio" name="A"></li>
       <li><input type="radio" name="B"></li>
       <li><input type="radio" name="C"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately it seems that `RadioGroup` only allows one to group radio buttons according to the grouping defined by their layout.

E.g.:

```
RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup("radioGroupA");

group.add( new Radio("myradio", new Model(1)) ;
```

The problem with this is that I cannot then lay out items the way I want.

Is there another way? Manually specifying the name and gathering results?

UPDATE: I notice that `Radio` can take a `RadioGroup` as a parameter. So one can do something like:

```
// create some groups
for (0..n) {
  RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup("myRadioGroup", new Model { .. } );
  groupArray.add(group)
}

//create a ListView for the RadioGroups so we can attach them to page
ListView radioListView = ListView("radioGroupList") { populate from groupArray }
add(radioListView);

// create our grid of radio buttons
// outer -> rows 
for (0..x) {
  // inner -> columns
  for (0..n)
    // supply group from our groupArray
    add( new Radio("myradio", new Model(1), groupArray.get(n) ));
  }
}
```

I can then add the `Radio`s and `RadioGroup`s to the form independently of layout, which has the desired effect in terms of the grouping.

```
<form>
  <span wicket:id="radioGroupList">
     <span wicket:id="radioGroup"/>
  </span>
  <ul> 
    <li><radio wicket:id="myradio"/></li>
```

But now, when I submit I am getting the following error:

> WicketMessage: submitted http post value [radio33] for RadioGroup component [2:tContainer:list:2:tPanel:myForm:orderedRadioGroupList:0:orderedRadioGroup] is illegal because it does not contain relative path to a Radio componnet. Due to this the RadioGroup component cannot resolve the selected Radio component pointed to by the illegal value. A possible reason is that componment hierarchy changed between rendering and form submission.

Any idea what this means?

The misspelled word "componment" suggests it's not seen too often.

I am using Wicket 1.4.12.

I found this Apache ticket that looks related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1055

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your component hierarchy is wrong. the Radio components have to be **inside** the radio group component as their javadoc says. since you **nested** radio groups you have to make sure that the Radio components you add are placed inside the **inner-most** RadioGroup instance. so, your markup should look like this:

```
<span wicket:id="group1">
    <span wicket:id="group2">
        <span wicket:id="group3">
            <ul>
                <li><input wicket:id="radio" type="radio"/>
                ...
```

problems with your current code is that you are using a ListView which creates a flat list out of your RadioGroups, not a **nested** list. and, you are adding your radios outside of the hierarchy of the groups.

Comment: how do you create the nested HTML markup for this if number of groups is variable? ie there could be 3,4,5,6,7.. groups.

Comment: you can do that with nested panels or fragments. here is a simple panel example: <wicket:panel><div wicket:id="group"><div wicket:id="inner"></div></div></wicket:panel> then to create the nesting you can keep nesting one panel inside the other into the "inner" tag. At the end you would add a WebMarkupContainer into the inner tag and add everything else to that.

Comment: ahhhh - ok - I didn't think of that. Thanks, I'll give that shot. It does seem a little unnecessary though.

Comment: yes. that is a shortcoming of the radiogroup/radio design. the radiogroup should not be made a component, rather just an object referenced by radios. something to refactor in 1.6 release.

Comment: I got it to work by following your advice, thanks. Unfortunately I now have quite a bit of code smell around the nested fragments. It might make more sense for me to move to drop downs instead longer term but at least I have learnt something in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bit and came to this simple solution:
Cheers, andre

JAVA Code:

```
RadioChoice<String> choice = new RadioChoice<>(
    "logger", new PropertyModel<>(model, "impl"), dao.getAvailableLoggers()
);
choice.setSuffix("\n");
form.add(choice);
```

Wicket Markup Code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .nowrap, .nowrap label {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<div class="nowrap">
    <wicket:container wicket:id="logger">x</wicket:container>
</div>
```